# Run program as administrator both Windows 7 and Windows XP

Tags: vb.net

Now i know you can do the following code to get it to run as administrator in Windows 7..

```
 Dim myProcess2 As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
            Dim startInfo2 As New ProcessStartInfo
            startInfo2.FileName = Application.StartupPath & "\installs\Assistant\RegisterSureFire.exe"
            startInfo2.Verb = "runas"
            myProcess2.StartInfo = startInfo2
            Application.DoEvents()
            myProcess2.Start()
```

But when you do this in windows XP, that box comes up asking if u want to run it in current user or in admin. Then usually my customer gets confused and gives us a call and blah blah... Is there a way i can make it detect the windows version and if its Below windows Vista then don't use the "runas"?

Or any other helpful methods would be great also!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Environment.OSVersion` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx).

Comment: I tested that code and it returns OSVersion: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0, it even says that it sometimes won't return the right operating system.... Note i'm using windows 8. This doesn't seem like its going to work for me, any other ways?

Comment: @eqiz: The actual version number of Windows 8 **is** Windows NT 6.2.  You can see this in the `winver` command.  XP is 5.2; Vista is 6.0.